# Backbone js + Require js + backbone relational + circular dependency + self references

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, circular-dependency, backbone-relational, self-reference

I've recently been experiencing issues with Backbone and Require JS as we have a fairly complex data model that I need to represent that is causing issues with circular dependencies and self references. I've read a bunch of posts online (none of which really worked) but I think I've found a solution. I'd therefore like to share this in the vein hope that it will help someone that experiences this issue, but also to ask you guys if you think there is a way to tidy things up.

The first issue was that I had models that referenced collections that referenced models that referenced collections, all of which created one big messy circular dependency. This frankly just broke the application. Here is an psuedo-code example:

```
Model A
  has Collection B

Collection B
  of Model B

Model B
  has Collection A
  has Collection C

Collection A
  of Model A

Collection C
  of Model C
```

The Backbone [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) state that this is possible by doing something like:

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.messages = new Messages;
    this.messages.url = '/mailbox/' + this.id + '/messages';
    this.messages.on("reset", this.updateCounts);
  },
```

I tried various ways of solving this for our needs but our complex nesting requirements break the hell out of Backbone. And so I stumbled upon [backbone relational](http://backbonerelational.org/#Store) and created a basic working representation of our data model (this involved creating a shim to work with Require JS). In essence this worked. And so I expanded the example so that Model C could also have instances of Collection C (self reference). Again this seemed to work. Excellent. However, applying the example to my application was more difficult - splitting Models and Collections up into individual files proved more difficult, as backbone relational expects the collection and model names to sit on the global namespace (bit tricky with Require and "use strict"). Because of our complex data model I wanted to represent relationships using string identifiers for forward referencing rather than explicit require references and this proved difficult too. I tried adding everything to the exports namespace but again this didn't work. Anyway I think I've found a solution by adding the collections and models to a custom namespace and then adding this namespace to the backbonerelational model scope. I've named my custom library "Orca" (cause killer whales are frankly awesome).

bootstrap.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery"        : "../bower_components/jquery/jquery",
    "underscore"    : "../bower_components/underscore-amd/underscore",
    "backbone"      : "../bower_components/backbone-amd/backbone",
    "relational"    : "../bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational",
    ...

  shim: {
    "underscore": {
      exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "relational": {
      deps: ["backbone"]
    },
    ...
```

app.js

```
define(["backbone", "relational", "libs/orca", "collections/a", "models/a", "collections/b", "models/b", "collections/c", "models/c"], function(Backbone, Relational, Orca){
  "use strict";

  var App = function(options) {
    this.initialize(otions);
  }; 

  App.prototype = _.extend(Backbone.Events, {

    initialize: function(options) {
      Orca.initialize();

      var a = new Orca.Relational.ModelA([],{});
    }
  }

  return App;
});
```

lib/orca.js

```
define(["backbone", "relational"], function(Backbone) {
  "use strict";

  var Orca = {
    Relational: {},

    initialize: function() {
      Backbone.Relational.store.addModelScope(this.Relational);      
    }
  };

  // I actually extend Backbone.RelationalModel so I can have custom methods,
  // e.g. "parse" but I've simplified the code for example's sake...
  Orca.Model = Backbone.RelationalModel;
  Orca.Collection = Backbone.Collection;

  return Orca;
});
```

collections/a.js

```
define(["backbone", "libs/orca"], function(Backbone, Orca) {
  "use strict";

  Orca.Relational.CollectionA = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
});
```

models/a.js

```
define(["backbone", "libs/orca"], function(Backbone, Orca) {
  "use strict";

  Orca.Relational.ModelA = Orca.Model.extend({
    relations: [
      {
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: "bs",
        relatedModel: "ModelB",
        includeInJSON: Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute,
        collectionType: "CollectionB",
        reverseRelation: {
          key: "a"
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

CollectionB and ModelB are similar so I've omitted these for brevity.

To demonstrate self referential:

```
define(["backbone", "libs/orca"], function(Backbone, Orca) {
  "use strict";

  Orca.Relational.ModelC = Orca.Model.extend({
    relations: [
      {
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: "cs",
        relatedModel: "ModelC",
        includeInJSON: Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute,
        collectionType: "CollectionC",
        reverseRelation: {
          key: "c"
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

So my bug bear about this code is that in app.js I create a new instance of ModelA. But because this references CollectionB which in turn is used by ModelB which in turn references Collection C and uses Model C then I have to reference all of these as require dependencies. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps adding Collections and Models to the "window" object might negate the need for a custom object but I like the idea of keeping things out of the global object anyway

Answer (score 1):

I've actually stopped using Backbone Relational and now I'm using [JJRelational](https://github.com/jj-studio/Backbone-JJRelational), as it allows many-to-many relationships. I've also negated the need to reference collections and models from within my main application file by creating a new file called "relational.js" that references the collections and models and returns them as attributes of an object. That way I only have to require "relational.js" if I need a new model or collection.

My relational.js file looks a bit like this:

```
define([
  // Models
  "models/broadcast",
  "models/version",
  // Collections
  "collections/broadcasts",
  "collections/versions"

], function(
  // Models
  Broadcast,
  Version,
  // Collections
  Broadcasts,
  Versions
) {
  "use strict";

  var _relational = {
    Broadcast: Broadcast,
    Version: Version,  

    Broadcasts: Broadcasts,
    Versions: Versions,
  };

  // Register the Collections
  Backbone.JJRelational.registerCollectionTypes({
    "Broadcasts": _relational.Broadcasts,
    "Versions": _relational.Versions    
  });

  // Provide JJRelational with model scope - pull request submitted to JJRelational to handle this
  Backbone.JJStore.addModelScope(_relational);

  return _relational;
});
```

Then in my main app.js:

```
define(["libs/relational"], function(Relational){
  var broadcast = new Relational.Broadcast();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever referred [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/index.html). I suggest you to have  a look at it once.

When I used it, I had faced similar circular dependencies and self references issues. The reason was I had mapped the `Models` on client side to the `Beans` on back-end which were mapped to the `Tables` using `Hibernate`. When you specify `one-to-many` relationship in `Hibernate` you need to specify reference of one entity into other and vice-versa. Then when these entities were returned by a Jersey service the conversion to JSON had circular dependencies. I could get rid of it on the back-end side using [some annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences). But there was no way to resolve it on `Backbone` side. I raised this issue with the author of `Backbone Associations` and they fixed it.

Hope this is helpful in some or the other way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and for suggesting another library